# How to connect to Fritz Box/AVM VPN with Windows 7?

Tags: networking, windows-7, vpn

How to establish a connection with *Fritz Box* VPN from **Windows 7** without any special client tools?

Some people means that *Fritz Box* uses IPSec with ESP mode...

Comment: could you solve the problem ? If yes, can you please share your findings ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions available how to connect to the VPN with different OSes (obviously without the FritzApp).
You could try to adept the instructions for Android found [here](http://service.avm.de/support/en/skb/FRITZ-Box-7270-int/1069:Using-an-Android-device-to-establish-a-VPN-connection-to-FRITZ-Box).

It should not make any difference if the client is actually an Android device or a windows machine.